# How do I do a `count_over_time` with a `group_left` statement?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like to know the number of created jobs in Kubernetes based on a specific label. The following is what I came up with. Since there are gaps between certain intervals I would like to do a count over time.

```
kube_job_created * on(job_name)
  group_left (label_cronjob_name)
  kube_job_labels{label_cronjob_name="sf-synch-abn"}
```

Where do I place the range vector selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
count(
    count_over_time(kube_job_created[1h]) 
  * on(job_name) group_left (label_cronjob_name)
    count_over_time(kube_job_labels{label_cronjob_name="sf-synch-abn"}[1h])
)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Wouldn't `count_over_time` aggregate the `kube_job_created` and the attribute `job_name` will be lost?

Comment: Brian, this seems to work. It's a bit counter-intuitive I find. Possibly due to my limited knowledge.